# Building reusable MVC-Control as razor-template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, reusability

I'm trying to build a reusable datetime-control inside my MVC5 application.
What is the best way to achieve code like:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12"> <!-- class(es) passed via htmlAttributes -->
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></div>
        <input class="form-control" id="StartDate" name="StartDate" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span></div>
        <input class="form-control" id="StartTime" name="StartTime" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div style="opacity: 0; height: 0;">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TheDateTime)
        <input id="Start" name="Start" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I want somethig like `@Html.DateTimePickerFor(m => m.Start, true, new object[]{})` to be used in my views, where the second param is `bool renderTimePicker`.

Creating a helper-method which the builds the markup with `TagBuilder` seems strange to me. This would also mean, that I have to release the application if I make changes.
I don't know how I can just save the markup as "plain" (cs)html and use it like mentioned above.

I already had

```
public static MvcHtmlString<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, bool? renderTimePicker = false, object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    return helper.EditorFor(expression, "DateTimePickerMarkup", ???); // how to pass renderTimePicker and htmlAttributes
}
```

but I am stuck here as I don't know how to pass my additional params.

As of data will be posted and could be part of a list, the name/id can also be something like `Model.AwesomeList[0].SomeDate` which makes it even more difficult for me.

**Edit #1**

I currently have this

```
    public static MvcHtmlString DateTimePickerFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, DateTime>> expression, bool? renderTimePicker = false, object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        var viewModel = new DateTimePickerViewModel
        {
            HtmlAttributes = htmlAttributes,
            TheDateTime = expression.Compile()(helper.ViewData.Model), // this gets me the current value
            RenderTimePicker = renderTimePicker ?? false
        };

        return helper.HtmlInternal.Partial("~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/_DateTimePicker.cshtml", viewModel);
    }
```

whereas `_DateTimePicker.cshtml` looks like above and renders as expected.

My new problem is, that my source-property is decorated with `Attributes` for validation.

If I use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TheDateTime)` it renders a simple `TextBox` without the needed data-attributes for validation, as of `TheDateTime` don't have one.
How can I pass my source property `Start` to `_DateTimePicker.cshtml`, so `Html.TextBoxFor()` will render also the validation-attibutes?

Comment: You can create a custom `EditorTempate` or an extension method, but combining both as your trying to do does not make much sense. Nor does passing the htmlAttributes as your doing - what element(s) would they be applied to?

Comment: Because I am using `bootstrap`, the `htmlAttributes` could contain something like `col-??-12` to manage the size of the `TextBox` depending on the device. (Will update my question to clarify)

Comment: Then you need one or the other. If you want the `EditorTemplate` version, you can pass the attributes to the template as `additionalViewData` (say `new { attributes = new { @class = "...." }}` and read it in the template - `@var attributes = ViewData("attributes") }` and then `<div class="@attributes">`

Comment: Please see my edited question. I'm getting closer but I think I'm still a million miles away...

Comment: Not even the hubble telescope could see you :) I repeat, use one of the other - a `HtmlHelper` extension method that generates your html, **or** a custom `EditorTemplate`/partial. Do not create an extension method that calls and outputs a custom `EditorTempate` or partial.

Comment: Ok. Will go the `EditorTemplate` way. But why "Do not create an extension method that calls and outputs a custom EditorTempate or partial."?